# Camel retry control with multiple exceptions

Tags: exception, apache-camel

Preface:  I'm fairly new to Camel, and after digesting Camel in action as best as possible, I'm adapting it to a project I'm on.  In this project, we have some rather complex error handling, and I want to make sure I can replicate this as we Camel-ize our code.

On our project (as most) there are a set of Exceptions we want to retry and a set that we don't - but more specifically, there are a set that we want to retry more than others (not all recoverable errors can be treated the same).   In this case, I was attempting to define an `onException` block to change the redelivery policy.  However, it seems that the Exchange maintains the count (`Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER`) and that this count is not dependent on which exception is thrown.  Is there a way to make this count be specific for a given exception?

For example - I have two exceptions `FooException` and `BarException`.  In my route (or really in the whole context), I want to retry FooExceptions 10 times, but `BarException`s should only retry 2 times.  So the context will contain:

```
<onException>
     <exception>my.exception.FooException</exception>
     <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="10" redeliveryDelay="2000"
</onException>

<onException>
      <exception>my.exception.BarException</exception>
      <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="5000"
</onException>
```

Now, the concern - if my application throws a `FooException` and retries 4 times (each time throwing a `FooException`) and then on the 5th attempt, it throws a `BarException`,  it seems that the way this works is the Exchange will have a `REDELIVERY_COUNTER` of 5, and when I reset the policy to only try twice, it (logically) concludes that the route should not be retried and throws the exception back out.  However, in my application `BarExceptions` should be retried twice, regardless of how many `FooExceptions` get thrown.  And likewise, if it alternates throwing Foo and Bar exceptions, I would like it to only increment the counter for the given exception.

The very end of Camel in Action promotes using a `retryWhile` - is this the only way to grab the kind of control I'm looking for?  Do I need to create a stateful bean that is aware of the count per exception?  Or am I overlooking something simple?  I want to make sure that as I approach this refactor I don't start us off on an ugly path.

Using Camel 2.10.1

Answer (score 1):

I checked your case with following test:

```
import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

/**
 * @author Illarion Kovalchuk
 *         Date: 12/7/12
 *         Time: 2:58 PM
 */
public class Test extends CamelTestSupport
{

    private static final String MIDDLE_QUEUE = "seda:middle";

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    private Processor processor = new Processor();

    @Test
    public void shouldRedeliverOnErrors() throws Exception
    {
        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("Body");
        template.sendBodyAndHeader(MIDDLE_QUEUE, "Body", "Header", "HV");
        resultEndpoint.assertIsNotSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder()
    {
        return new RouteBuilder()
        {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception
            {

                onException(FooException.class)
                        .redeliveryDelay(2000)
                        .maximumRedeliveries(10);

                onException(BarException.class)
                        .redeliveryDelay(5000)
                        .maximumRedeliveries(2);

                from(MIDDLE_QUEUE)
                        .bean(Processor.class, "process")
                        .to(resultEndpoint)
                        .end();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class Processor
    {
        private static AtomicLong retryState = new AtomicLong(0L);

        public static void process(Exchange e) throws FooException, BarException
        {
            long rs = retryState.getAndAdd(1L);
            if (rs < 4)
            {
                System.err.println("Foo Attempt "+ rs);
                throw new FooException();
            }
            if (rs == 4)
            {
                System.err.println("Bar Attempt "+ rs);
                throw new BarException();
            }
            System.err.println("Normal Attempt "+ rs);
        }
    }

    public static class FooException extends Throwable
    {
    }

    private static class BarException extends Throwable
    {
    }
}
```

As the result, your concirn was approved: delivery attempts gets exhausted after BarException, even if we have only 4 FooExceptions and 1 BarException.

Unfortunately I can't answer your question fully right now, but I am digging into it and will updated my unswer if get something new.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the order you define your exceptions, e.g.:

```
<onException>
      <exception>my.exception.BarException</exception>
      <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="5000"
</onException>

<onException>
     <exception>my.exception.FooException</exception>
     <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="10" redeliveryDelay="2000"
</onException>
```

Comment: If you use Shaman's test case, reordering doesn't seem to change the output. I'll try to test this in the Spring configuration when I get a chance.